# Only outputs the sequence of array entries from the lowest score up to the largest score range

Tags: c++, arrays, sequence

so i am new to coding, and i am having trouble to print out from the lowest to the highest number with their frequency. example if the user inputs                                                     35 5
50 2
41 6
42 3
48 4
42 2                                                                                                it should print out                                                                                 35: 5
36: 0
37: 0
38: 0
39: 0
40: 0
41: 6
42: 5
43: 0
44: 0
45: 0
46: 0
47: 0
48: 4
49: 0
50: 2                                                                                               please guys help!!

Comment: I have not unserstood how the array has to be outputed.

Comment: to make it clear ,,,,, the numbers from 35 to 50 are the scores ,,,and the single numbers like 5, 2, 6, 3, 4 are the frequency and the numbers should print out vertically

Answer (score 0):

It will be simpler to do the assignment if to define an array of std::pair. For example

```
std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> a = {  { 35, 5 }, { 50, 2 }, { 41, 6 },  { 42, 3 }, { 48, 4 }, { 42, 2 } };
```

and then you can use standard algorithm `std::minmax_element`

For example

```
auto p = std::minmax( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ),
                      []( const std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> &lhs, const std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> & rhs )
                      {
                         return ( lhs.first < rhs.first );
                      } );
```

And then you can use a loop for example as

```
for ( unsigned i = p.first->first; i <= p.second->first; i++ )
{
    // using std::accumulate or the range based for statement to calcukate the sum of frequencies
}
```

But as I guess you do not know neither std::pair nor standard algorithms. So you should show what you did yourself so far.:)

Comment: yeah i know this is all pretty new. but this my code so far                 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 const int max_score = 50;
 int score[max_score];
 int frequency =0;
 int scores;
 int input;
cin >> input;
 for (int i =0; i < input ; i++)
cout << i ;
cout << "please enter the quiz score and frequency" << endl;
 for (int i =0; i < max_score; i++)
{
cin >> score[i]>> frequency;
  if (score[i] < 0)
  break;
  else
frequency ++;
}
 return 0;
}

Comment: i think this is better            
int main()                                                                .
{                                                                         
cout << "please enter the quiz score and frequency" << endl;              .
 for (int i =0; i < max_score; i++)                                .
{                                                                         .
cin >> score[i]>> frequency;                                              .

frequency ++;
}
 return 0;
}